# Poner color a un evento de Google Calendar

Tags: android, api, google-calendar

Estoy creando eventos en el calendario de Google y quiero asignarle un color especifico al evento, pero no lo consigo, me sale el color del calendario.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente, el cual crea el evento perfectamente.

```
 public static long addUVEvent (Activity activity, long calendarId, String title, String description, String location, Date dateBegin, Date dateEnd ,boolean allDay, boolean needReminder, boolean needMailService){

        long startMillisEpoch;
        long endMillisEpoch;

        // calculamos la fecha de inicio y la de fin
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.setTime(dateBegin);
        startMillisEpoch = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();

        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.setTime(dateEnd);
        endMillisEpoch = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

        //Preparamos el evento
        ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);

        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillisEpoch);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillisEpoch);

//      A secondary color key for the individual event. NULL or an empty string are reserved for indicating that the event does not use a key for looking up the color.
//      The provider will update EVENT_COLOR automatically when a valid key is written to this column.
//      The key must reference an existing row of the CalendarContract.Colors table. @see Colors
//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR_KEY, eventColor); //string
        //eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR_KEY, Color.parseColor("blue"));
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.BLUE);

        // NOTA: Todos los eventos deben tener un timezone.
        // Sino la aplicacion lanzara un IllegalArgumentException.
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, (allDay)?1:0); 

        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.GUESTS_CAN_INVITE_OTHERS, 1);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.GUESTS_CAN_MODIFY, 0);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.GUESTS_CAN_SEE_GUESTS, 1);

//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_DEFAULT);
//        // Default(0),          CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_DEFAULT
//        // Confidential(1),     CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_CONFIDENTIAL
//        // Private(2),          CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE
//        // Public(3),           CalendarContract.Events.ACCESS_PUBLIC

//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS , CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_TENTATIVE);
//        // This information is sufficient for most entries
//        // tentative (0),       CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_TENTATIVE
//        // confirmed (1)        CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED
//        // or canceled (2)      CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CANCELED

//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_FREE);
//        // Busy(0),             CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY
//        // Free(1),             CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_FREE
//        // Tentative(2),        CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_TENTATIVE

//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true

//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=20080222T000000Z"); // The recurrence rule for the event FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=10;WKST=SU;BYDAY=TU,TH
//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, CalendarIntentHelper.EVENT_TYPE_YEARLY);
//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EXRULE, 1); //The recurrence exception rule for the event
//
//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.RDATE, 1); // The recurrence dates for the event
//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EXDATE, 1); //The recurrence exception dates for the event

        //for one hour
//        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "+P1H");//The duration of the event in RFC2445 format, only for recurring events

        // insert event to calendar

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            PermissionUtil.requestCalendarPermission(activity);

            return -1;
        }

        Uri calUri = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            calUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventValues);
        }else{
            calUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
        }

        if (calUri != null) {

            long eventID = -1;
            try {
                eventID = Long.parseLong(calUri.getLastPathSegment());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            }

            if(eventID != -1) {
                if (needReminder) {
                    /***************** Event: Reminder(with alert) Adding reminder to event *******************/

                    ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

                    reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID , eventID);
                    reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES , 5); // Default value of the system. Minutes is a integer
//                    reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES,  60 * 12); //12 horas
                    reminderValues.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD , CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
                    // Alert Methods:
                    // Default(0),      CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_DEFAULT
                    // Alert(1),        CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT
                    // Email(2),        CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_EMAIL
                    // SMS(3),          CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_SMS
                    // ALARM(4),        CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALARM


                    Uri reminderUri = null;

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                        reminderUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminderValues);
                    }else{
                        reminderUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);
                    }
                }

                /***************** Event: Meeting(without alert) Adding Attendies to the meeting *******************/

                if (needMailService) {

                    /********
                     * To add multiple attendees need to insert ContentValues multiple
                     * times
                     ***********/
                    ContentValues attendeesValues = new ContentValues();

                    attendeesValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.EVENT_ID , eventID);
                    attendeesValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME , "pepe"); // Attendees name
                    attendeesValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL , "mobile.programming.lisitt@gmail.com");// Attendee  Email id
                    attendeesValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_RELATIONSHIP , CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_NONE);
                    // Relationship_None(0),    CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_NONE
                    // Relationship_Attendee(1),CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_ATTENDEE
                    // Organizer(2),            CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_ORGANIZER
                    // Performer(3),            CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_PERFORMER
                    // Speaker(4)               CalendarContract.Attendees.RELATIONSHIP_SPEAKER
                    attendeesValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_TYPE , CalendarContract.Attendees.TYPE_NONE);
                    // None(0),                 CalendarContract.Attendees.TYPE_NONE
                    // Required(1),             CalendarContract.Attendees.TYPE_REQUIRED
                    // Optional(2),             CalendarContract.Attendees.TYPE_OPTIONAL
                    attendeesValues.put(CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS , CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_NONE);
                    // NOne(0),                 CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_NONE
                    // Accepted(1),             CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_ACCEPTED
                    // Decline(2),              CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_DECLINED
                    // Invited(3),              CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_INVITED
                    // Tentative(4)             CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS_TENTATIVE

                    Uri attendeuesesUri = null;

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                        attendeuesesUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Attendees.CONTENT_URI, attendeesValues);
                    }else{
                        attendeuesesUri = activity.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(attendeesUriString), attendeesValues);
                    }
                }
            }

            return eventID;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu código, estas usando un color azul:

```
 eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.BLUE);
```

Con

> **[EVENT_COLOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#EVENT_COLOR)** puedes cambiar el color de un evento individual.

y puedes usar el [RGB](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm) del color que desees, simplemente agrega el color hexadecimal, por ejemplo un color [azul](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/blue-color.htm) claro:

```
eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.parseColor("#ADD8E6));
```

También puedes usar la constante definida en el SDK, como en el caso de tu código que es el color azul:

```
eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.EVENT_COLOR, Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y funciona, aunque en mi tablet con versión 4.0.4 sigue apareciendo el color por defecto del calendario, supongo que dependerá de la versión de android del dispositivo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esta linea:

```
eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

en lugar de esta:

```
eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y funciona, aunque en mi tablet con versión 4.0.4 sigue apareciendo el color por defecto del calendario, supongo que dependerá de la versión de android del dispositivo.